# How can i get the last day of the month given a date?

Tags: sql, sas

I am trying to get the number of records from a table but only when the date is the last day of the month. I am connecting to teradata and trying the following:

```
PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE A AS SELECT DISTINCT DATE, COUNT(*)
        FROM TERADATA_LIB.SOME_TABLE
            WHERE DATE = intnx('month', DATE,0, 'E');
QUIT;
```

but apparently the intx function is not valid inside `PROC SQL`.

How else can i get this done?

Thanks.

Comment: Is that your full code or are you using SQL Pass through with a connect statement? INTNX() is valid in SQL code.

Answer (score 1):

Is the apparentness from a LOG message, or the fact that your result set is not as you expect?

The DATE variable in the Teradata table could be a datetime value.

Try `DATEPART` with the `INTNX('MONTH'` or use datetime intervals `DTMONTH` and `DTDAY`.  Also, is the SQL example correct? You select `DATE, COUNT(*)` but do not have a `GROUP` clause.  Do you *want* SAS to automatically remerge the summary statistic `COUNT` to every record in the result set?

Example:

Generate hourly datetime values for 8 months.  8*24=192 records will occur on the last day of a month.

```
data have(label='5833 hourly records, expect 8*24=192 records with last day of month');
  do date = '01-JAN-2022T0:0:0'dt to '01-SEP-2022T0:0:0'DT by '01:00't;
    seq + 1;
    output;
  end;
run;

* criteria uses DATEPART and MONTH interval;
proc sql;
  create table want(label='How many records are dated for the last day of a month') as 
  select 
    count(*) as count
  from 
    have
  where
    datepart(date) = intnx('month',datepart(date),0,'E')
  ;

* criteria uses datetime value and DT intervals DTMONTH and DTDAY;
proc sql;
  create table want(label='How many records are dated for the last day of a month') as 
  select 
    count(*) as count
  from 
    have
  where
    intnx('DTMONTH',date,0,'E') = intnx('DTDAY', date, 0, 'E')
  ;
```